# The CSharp package did not load properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I am having an issue with my Visual Studio 2017 when creating a new solution or opening a solution which says me with a error message CSharp package did not load properly this may be because of configuration change. Get more information in ActivityLog.XML File.

I had tried repairing my Visual Studio and completely reinstalling it.

I had also tried deleting the local and roaming cache in app data folder path to the following:
C:\Users\Ashutosh\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_03bf2985
C:\Users\Ashutosh\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_03bf2985

I have uploaded my activitylog.xml file on OneDrive, shared the link below. Please have a look on it and provide me with a proper solution to this issue.

[ActivityLog.xml](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aj5d9h9G4jVsj1bUL4H3s0lnUnwx)

Comment: This seems related to a corrupted .Net framework, rather than a problem in visual studio. Which system are you running on, and what version of the .Net framework do you have installed?

Comment: I am using windows 10 64 bit operating system and .Net Framework is 4.7.1